# How am I writing this constructor?

Tags: object, constructor

How am I writing the object types "AddressInfo homeAddress" and "AddressInfo workAddress" in constructor?!

```
public Employee(String name,AddressInfo homeAddress, AddressInfo workAddress, int debt)  
{
    this.name=name ;
   ???
   ???
    this.debt=debt;

}
```

Comment: I have written below the code. I dont know how to write in constructor these types of objects.(AddressInfo homeAddress,AddressInfo workAddress)

Comment: Those are variables just like any other variables.  You need to learn the basics of C# syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Just copy-and-think-and-paste the code that initializes `this.name`. Except for the different variable and type name, this is exactly the same.

Comment: public Employee(String name,AddressInfo homeAddress, AddressInfo workAddress, int debt)  
{
    this.name=name ;
   this.AddressInfo homeAddress=AddressInfo homeAddress;
   this.AddressInfo workAddress=AddressInfo workAddress;
    this.debt=debt;

} is that right?

Comment: No, of course not. Look at the initialization for the `name` field. It just says `this.name = name`, and you tried to make it `this.String name = String name`, which is wrong.

Comment: I can't find the right way  to write them (AddressInfo homeAddress, AddressInfo workAddress)